# How can I assign an anchor tag to expand content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of things with links to click for more information which use anchor tags to move down the page.  Since there is quite a bit of additional information I have it hidden in expandable/collapsable sections.

So far all I've managed to come up with is an expand collapse on the section itself.  I know basically nothing about Javascript so what I have include is some stuff I pieced together from some other sites and research.

I would like for the 'click more' anchor tag link to expand the section automatically when clicked, but something that also collapses it similar to what I have now.

Here is the js I managed to pull together

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(tbid,lnkid) {
        if (document.all) {
            document.getElementById(tbid). style.display = document.getElementById(tbid).style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";
        } 
        else {
            document.getElementById(tbid).style.display = document.getElementById(tbid).style.display == "table" ? "none" : "table";
        } 

        document.getElementById(lnkid).value = document.getElementById(lnkid).value == "[-] Collapse" ? "[+] Expand" : "[-] Collapse";
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .hangingIndent {
        text-indent: -24px;
        padding-left: 24px;
    }
    #tbl1 {display:none;}
    #lnk1 {
        border:none;
        background:none;
        width:85px;
    }
</style>
```

And here is an example of the body

```
<body style="background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: 20;">
    <p style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; padding:0px 20px;" class="hangingIndent">
        <input type="checkbox">
            <strong>Item one</strong><br />
            <em>For more information about Item one <a href="#Item1">click here</a>!</em>
    </p>
    <br />

    <table width="800px" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
        <tr height="1">
            <td bgcolor="#333333" colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE" height="15">
            <td>
                <strong><a id="Item1">Item one</a></strong>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#EEEEEE" align="right">
                <input id="lnk1" type="button" value="[+] Expand" onclick="toggle_visibility('tbl1','lnk1');">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" id="tbl1">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <p style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; padding:0px 20px;">Lots of extra information about Item one</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
</body>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at jQuery, a lot of this kind of thing is done for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery may be your best route, and in particular the slideToggle or show and hide functions.
In addition, have a peek at jQuery ui accordion

[A jquery accordion may be your best route](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Answer (score 0):

to hide elements:

`document.getElementById(idOfElement).style.display="none"`

to show them:

`document.getElementById(idOfElement).style.display="block"`

lets make a function

```
function toggleElementDisplay(elementID){

    element = document.getElementById(elementID);

    if(element.getPropertyValue("display") == "block"){
        element.style.display="none";
    } else {
        element.style.display="block";
    }

}
```

To use it do it like this

```
<body>
<div id="click" onClick="toggleElementDisplay('stuff');">Toggle</div>
<div id="stuff">Hello</div>
<script>
function toggleElementDisplay(elementID) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID),
        style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
        display = style.getPropertyValue("display");

    if (display == "block") {
        element.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        element.style.display = "block";
    }

}
</script>
</body>
```

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw5fD/7/) to help